# Set value of pandas data frame on conditional

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I can't find a similar question for this query. However, I have a pandas dataframe where I want to use two of the columns to make conditional and if its true, replace the values in one of these columns.

For example. One of my columns is the 'itemname' and the other is the 'value'.
the 'itemname' may be repeated many times. I want to check for each 'itemname', if all other items with the same name have value 0, then replace these 'value' with 100.

I know this should be simple, however I cannot get my head around it.

Just to make it clearer, here

```
    itemname value
0      a       0
1      b       100
2      c       0
3      a       0
3      b       75
3      c       90
```

I would like my statement to change this data frame to

```
    itemname value
0      a       100
1      b       100
2      c       0
3      a       100
3      b       75
3      c       90
```

Hope that makes sense. I check if someone else has asked something similar and couldnt find something in this case.

Comment: So if all values of same item equals 0 you want them to be 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `transform` with `any`:

```
df.loc[~df.groupby('itemname').value.transform('any'), 'value'] = 100
```

#### Using `numpy.where`:

```
s = ~df.groupby('itemname').value.transform('any')
df.assign(value=np.where(s, 100, df.value))
```

#### Using addition and multiplication:

```
s = ~df.groupby('itemname').value.transform('any')
df.assign(value=df.value + (100 * s))
```

Both produce the correct output, however, `np.where` and the final solution don't modify the DataFrame in place:

```
  itemname  value
0        a    100
1        b    100
2        c      0
3        a    100
3        b     75
3        c     90
```

---

***Explanation***

```
~df.groupby('itemname').value.transform('any')
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
3    False
3    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Since `0` is a falsey value, we can use `any`, and negate the result, to find groups where all values are equal to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` to create a mask. Then assign via `pd.DataFrame.loc` and Boolean indexing:

```
mask = df.groupby('itemname')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(0).all())
df.loc[mask.astype(bool), 'value'] = 100

print(df)

  itemname  value
0        a    100
1        b    100
2        c      0
3        a    100
3        b     75
3        c     90
```

Answer (score 3):

**If all your values are positive or 0**

Could use transform with sum and check if 0:

```
m = (df.groupby('itemname').transform('sum') == 0)['value']
df.loc[m, 'value'] = 100
```

Comment: You could have the variables not all equal `0`, and still have their sum be `0`. For example, you could have one value be `-50` and another be `50`, thus the sum is `0` but the values are obviously not equal to `0`.

Comment: @JoePatten You are right ofc. I added an if on top. I just assumed positive values.

Comment: @jpp adding that in.

Comment: I think `(df.groupby('itemname').value.transform('sum') == 0)` is safer (also faster), since you could run into issues if a column throws an error when being added

Comment: Also, why not use the absolute value before checking for `sum`, it would make this solution extend to negative numbers as well

Comment: @user3483203 Yeah I thought about that but that would be one more computational operation and tbh if values are >0 it feels unnecessary. Falsy data could be picked up by doing a column check. But indeed I would also go for abs solution.